# What do my NodeJs Firebase read/write functions actually return?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, async-await, promise

I come from a language with no promises :-(

I want to code some NodeJS utility functions like these to interface with FireBase. It is my understanding that all FB functions return a promise (but, feel free to correct me).

```
exports.writeToFireBase(url, value){
    try{
        promise = await admin.database().ref(url).set(value);   
        return promise;
    }

    catch(exception){
        exports.unhandledException(exception);
    }
}

 exports.readFromFireBase(url){
    try{
        let value = admin.database().ref(url).once("value");

        return value;
    }

    catch(exception){
        exports.unhandledException(exception);
    }
}
```

What are functions actually returning?

In the write case, I guess it is either a promise, or nothing?

In the read case, will my function return the actual data, or a promise to that data?  `Await` looks to me like it is blocking, but I suspect that I am wrong, and that  promise to the data is returned from my read function.

Can someone please clarify, before I base too much code on erroneous assumptions?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense at all. e.g. You are calling `exports.writeToFireBase(url, value)` but then you have a block (weirdly starting on the same line) that is pointless (since no `let` or `const` variables are declared in it). I don't think that code means what you think it means.

Comment: "What are functions actually returning?" — Which functions, specifically?

Comment: "Await looks to me like it is blocking, but I suspect that I am wrong" — Try [some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

Comment: Aha! Await "Returns the fulfilled value of the promise, or the value itself if it's not a Promise". Now it is clear (and, obviously, it blocks).  It I don't await and just return the FB function, then I guess that I am returning a promise ( do I need to `return new Promise (FB function call)`?

Comment: "obviously, it blocks" — No. "An await splits execution flow, allowing the caller of the async function to resume execution"

Comment: "do I need to return new Promise (FB function call)" — Definitely. Definitely. Not.

Comment: Splits execution? Like yield?  On the line after await the docs say that I have the value of the resolved promise, so await is sort of wrapping a callback, allowing something else to run, then resuming on the next line when the callback us called?

Comment: Yes. That's right.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much. If you want to post an answer, basically just a summary of these comments, I will accept it. It might help others in future. Thanks again.